# Select data from previous record in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Please can you help a relatively noob to crystal reports being used in VS2015.
I have a report generated from an sql database but im struggling to select the right piece of data for my report.

The psuedo code goes something like:

'CurrentLocation' = Location where
"Select (top1) Location
where weeknumber < @weeknumber
order by fleetNumber Desc"

I hope that makes sense. I am already grouping by week number and ordering by date in the report.

Comment: What is previous record?

Comment: Sorry Siva i Dont understand what you mean? The record i am trying to get the data from is not the previous record in the set. The record would be the previous record with the same Fleet ID with could be hundreds of rows away from the current one!

Comment: That can be done...but you need to know which record you want to get?